# alter column (using + where)

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter

I work with postgresql 9.3, 
I use this query to convert timestamp column to UTC.

```
ALTER TABLE table 
ALTER timestamp TYPE timestamp 
USING timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ;
```

I need to add WHERE cluose to the query :

```
ALTER TABLE table 
ALTER timestamp TYPE timestamp where timestamp < '2015-01-06 00:00:00'
USING timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' ;
```

but, this is didn't work .
there no clear resource on how to do it.

Comment: what is the requirement for altering  column for particular rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply ALTER TYPE construction only to whole column, not to some rows. If you want to convert timestamp value you should use UPDATE instead.

Comment: Yes , you're right. it works i used : UPDATE table set timestamp = timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
where timestamp < '2015-01-06 00:00:00'

Answer (score 2):

you can't alter table column type using where, because "where" is DML and "alter" is DDL. Use update whe